# Scheme - Maximum Recursion Depth Error (Is this recursive call in a tail context?)

Tags: performance, recursion, scheme, tail-recursion

In a turtle graphics function call written in Scheme, I receive a maximum recursion depth reached error. Since the recursive call is the conditional outcome of an if statement, the recursive call is in a tail context. In Scheme tail recursion should compute in constant space and not reach a recursion depth limit. Am I mistaken thinking that my recursive call (surrounded by asterisks) is in a tail context?

```
(define (draw)
  (hideturtle) (pu) (color "gold")(bgcolor "black")
  (define rr 155) (define r 35) (define d 125) (define theta 0.05)
  (define steps (* 100000 (floor (/ (* 6 3.14) theta))))

  (define (spiro steps angle)

    (if (<= steps 0) (pu) 
      ( (color "gold")

      (define x 
        (- (* (- rr r) (cos angle)) 
          (* d (cos (* (/ (- rr r) r) angle)))))

      (define y 
        (- (* (- rr r) (sin angle)) 
          (* d (sin (* (/ (- rr r) r) angle)))))

      (goto x y) (pd) (begin_fill)

      (spiro (- steps 1) (+ angle 0.2)) ;;;; ** HERE **
       )

      )
    )
  (spiro steps 0)
  (exitonclick)
)
```

Comment: You're missing a `begin` as the body of the else. Bet it's evaluating all the arguments and if it didn't error first, eventually tries to treat whatever `(color "gold")` returns as a procedure to invoke with the rest of the return values as arguments.

Comment: ^Was about to say that. Make sure you don’t skip using `begin` — it is only possible to omit it in specific special forms. If that doesn’t fix it, what version of Scheme are you using?

Comment: Should look something like `(if (<= steps 0) (pu) (begin (color "gold") ...))`

Comment: Thanks fixed! Begin was the solution. My question now, are the operands not evaluated in order without begin?

Comment: Scheme makes more sense if you abandon the "I'm used to curly-brace languages" parenthesis layout (at least helped me immensely - the conventions are conventional for good reasons). Scheme doesn't really have that kind of block structure.

Comment: @chriswillgard Without `begin` the list is evaluated as a procedure call with the fist element as operands that will fail if the first does not evaluate to a procedure tht can be called. The order of evaluation of operands are in consistent but undefined order according to the report, which means many do left to right and right to left. I have yet to encounter a different evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

You code contains `( (color "gold") .... (spiro ... ...) )` which is equivalent to

```
  (let
       ( (a  (color "gold"))
         ....................
         (z  (spiro ... ...))
         )
    (a ...... z))
```

so the call `(spiro ... ...)` is definitely self-evidently ***not*** in tail position.

*Whatever* the order of evaluation of the init-expressions in `let` as in the original `lambda` is, the final call to `(a ... z)` is still done *afterwards*.

Comment: \[reply to your edit of my deleted answer, dunno how to do that other than this]: your edit on it makes it less bad but I still think your answer is better, as mine was unduly rude (fed up with poorly laid out code!).